# How to Upload and Retrieve images in application in which Client is HTML+Jquery and Server is based on Rest Services

Tags: jquery, rest

I am developing application in which Client is based on HTML+CSS3+JQuery and Server is based
on REST services.

**Right now I am stuck with Problem of Uploading and Retrieving images in my application.
I want to have solution which will be compatible on all browsers.**

Can you please suggest me how can Handle(Upload & Retrieve) images in my application.

**Use Case:** User logged in to my application and want to upload his/her image as profile image, application should store user image and display back when user logged in.

your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I found the solution to my problem**
Below is the example to upload and retrieve images using HTML+AJAX(JQUERY)+REST

**Html Code:**

```
enter code here
<html>
<input type="file" id="uphoto" class="textFieldsReg">
<input type="button" value="upload photo" onClick="uploadImage()">
<input type="button" value="get photo" onClick="getImage()">   
<img src="" id="theimage">             
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
enter code here


 function getImage() 
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://<server>:<port>/getImage/',
    type: 'POST',    
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType:'text',
    }).done(
    function( json ) 
    {
      document.getElementById("theimage").width='100';
      document.getElementById("theimage").height='100';
      document.getElementById("theimage").src='data:image/png;base64,'+json;      
     }
    })
    .fail(
    function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) 
    {
      var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
      console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
  });

}

enter code here
function uploadImage(event)
{
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', $('#uphoto').get(0).files[0]);
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://<server>:<port>/uploadImage/',
  type: 'POST',
  data:formData ,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  }).done(
  function( json ) 
  {
    console.log('done');
  }).fail(
  function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) 
  {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
  });
}
```

**REST code:**

```
enter code here
    @POST
    @Path("/uploadImage/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(List<Attachment> attachments) {
        for(Attachment attr : attachments) {
            DataHandler handler = attr.getDataHandler();
            try {
                InputStream stream = handler.getInputStream();
                MultivaluedMap map = attr.getHeaders();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://image.jpg"));

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                stream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }     
        return Response.ok("file uploaded").build();
    }
enter code here



        @POST
        @Path("/getImage/")
        public String getImage() 
        {
            byte[] bytes = null ;
            try 
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "C://image.jpg" );
                bytes = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(fis);
            }catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String obj = Base64.encode(bytes);          
            return obj;
        }
```